# Get site-packages directory in nox

Tags: python, nox

In tox, I can [get the site-packages directory of the current environment](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=envsitepackagesdir#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections) with the `envsitepackagesdir` magic variable. How do I do the same thing in `nox`? This is particularly useful when trying to get coverage of my package.

```
import nox

@nox.session()
def test(session):
    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.run('pytest', '--cov', f'{session.virtualenv.site_packages_dir}/mypackage')
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are actually installing a nox environment (not using `venv_backend='none'`), you can calculate this from the location of the virtual environment and `platform.sys`:

```
import nox

@nox.session()
def test(session):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        site_packages = f'{session.virtualenv.location}/Lib/site-packages'
    else:
        site_packages = f'{session.virtualenv.location}/lib/python{session.python}/site-packages'

    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.run('pytest', '--cov', f'{site_packages}/mypackage')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `envsitepackagesdir` is not actually necessary for coverage. You can pass the module name to `--cov` and `coverage` will compute the coverage on that module wherever it is imported:

```
import nox

@nox.session()
def test(session):
    session.install('.')
    session.install('pytest', 'pytest-cov')
    session.run('pytest', '--cov', 'mypackage')
```